# WSO2 Integrator: Unable to locate the specified WSDL to build the service Error

Tags: wso2, wsdl, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I have specified a custom WSDL in a proxy service with:
`<publishWSDL key="conf:sample_proxy_wsdl1.wsdl" preservePolicy="true"/>` according to [this](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/protocol-switching/switching_from_HTTPS_to_JMS/) doc. But I keep getting the below error. What is **key** in this case?

```
Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Couldn't build the proxy service : HttpToJms. Unable to locate the specified WSDL to build the service
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService.handleException(ProxyService.java:978)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService.buildAxisService(ProxyService.java:622)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.ProxyServiceDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(ProxyServiceDeployer.java:84)
    ... 73 more
```

This is what I see in the registry resource editor. Tried giving the deploy path `publishWSDL key="conf:/_system/governance/endpoints/sample_proxy_wsdl1.wsdl"` but still same error.
[image: This is what I see in the registry resource editor]

Comment: Are you on MI or EI? Do you have a registry resource project? Also, how are you building the source?

Comment: MI, using registry resource module within the project. Trying to run using the Integration studio's embedded MI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WSDL can be in WSO2 registry governance (gov) repository or configuration (conf) repository. According to the documentation, which you have follow it looks like you don't have proper registry path.

1. If you are using Governance repository key should looks like: `key="gov:/endpoints/sample_proxy_wsdl1.wsdl"` . And looking from your screenshot, with Registry resource editor, **this should be proper for your**.
2. If you are using Configuration repository, it should look like: `key="conf:/endpoints/sample_proxy_wsdl1.wsdl""`